# Running async() from non async without waiting

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

In my code why does QueueTasks() not run asyncronusly to the main method?  Is there a different way to call is so that it does?

I want `QueueTasks(thingsToProcess, cts.Token);` to start the async method and then carry on executing code.

When I google running async from non async everything suggests using Task.Wait() but I don't want to wait, I just want to trigger the process.  I also googled making main thread async but found contradictory advice so I am not sure what the exact issue is here.  I am using .net 4.5.

```
class Program
{
    private static SemaphoreSlim maxThreads = new SemaphoreSlim(5);
    private static readonly object syncLock = new object();
    private static readonly Random getrandom = new Random();
    private static int inQueue = 0;
    public static int GetRandomNumber(int min, int max)
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        { // synchronize
            return getrandom.Next(min, max);
        }
    }
    static async Task DoSomething(string input, int row, SemaphoreSlim theSem)
    {
        theSem.Wait();
        inQueue++;
        int delay = GetRandomNumber(0, 5000);
        await Task.Delay(delay);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: Doing something to {1}", row,input));
        inQueue--;
        theSem.Release();

    }
    static async Task QueueTasks(List<string> things, CancellationToken ct)
    {
            int taskNumber = 0;
            foreach (string thing in things)
            {
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No more tasks being queued");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    maxThreads.Wait();
                    DoSomething(thing, ++taskNumber, maxThreads);
                    maxThreads.Release();
                }
            }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // build list of 100 random strings to represent input
        List<string> thingsToProcess = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            thingsToProcess.Add(Path.GetRandomFileName());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Starting queue");

        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        // I want this to initiate a queue starting but not stop the flow of code.
        QueueTasks(thingsToProcess, cts.Token);           

        // This should run immediately after queue starts   
        Console.WriteLine("Hit X to stop current queue"); 
        ConsoleKeyInfo cancel = Console.ReadKey();

        while (cancel.KeyChar != 'x')
        {
            cancel = Console.ReadKey();
        }

        if (cancel.KeyChar == 'x')
        {
            cts.Cancel();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("You requested a cancellation. {0} threads left to process", inQueue));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Operation completed without interuption");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`async` is not a keyword that magically makes your method asynchronous! It just allows you to use the `await` keyword inside of it - which you're not doing. Your method is completely synchronous, so it will not return until it's finished.

If you did use `await` at some point, that's when `QueueTasks` would return, and you could continue executing `Main`.

Apart from that, your code is quite thread-unsafe, so you're lucky it actually doesn't run multi-threaded (actually, it does run on multiple threads - but at least only a about 2-3 threads at a time) :) A great starter on multi-threading is http://www.albahari.com/threading/.

The easiest thing you can do is simply to wrap the `QueueTasks` method in `Task.Run`. This will cause it to run on a new thread, parallel to the callee.

The second easiest thing would be to use `await` inside of `QueueTasks` when you're "waiting" for the semaphore - `await maxThreads.WaitAsync()` instead of `maxThreads.Wait`. Note that you should remove the wait inside of `DoSomething` - you're throwing the semaphore slots away; it's actually quite possible to deadlock your code like this (all five slots being taken by the outside `Wait`, which will prevent the `Wait` in `DoSomething` from ever unblocking).

The hardest thing would be to actually learn how to properly handle a producer-consumer queue with parallel execution and throttling. Again, http://www.albahari.com/threading/ is a great starter :)

Comment: Thanks! That tutorial was really good, cleared up a lot of confusion I was getting from just looking at class info on msdn.  I knew I was doing it all wrong but couldn't find a good entry point to understanding what was going on.